# Initialization of a pointer immediately after calling deleteLater()

Tags: qt, pointers, qt4

Is it safe to immediately initialize a Qt4 pointer after calling `deleteLater()`? I.e. is the next code safe?

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Text");
// doing smth
label->deleteLater();
label = new QLabel("Other text");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#deleteLater) (which you are welcome to consult yourself in the future), your code is perfectly fine. But note that your question is wrong, since you are not "initializing" `label` a second time; you are merely *assigning* to it.

After the assignment, `label` simply points to an entirely different, new object, and the original object is registered for eventual deletion, so all is well.